# Class Design and Structure Online Web Store

Tags: design-patterns, uml, class-design, class, class-diagram

I hope I have asked this in the right forum.

Basically, we're designing an Online Store and I am designing the class structure for ordering a product and want some clarification on what I have so far:

So a customer comes, selects their product, chooses the quantity and selects 'Purchase' (I am using the Facade Pattern - So subsystems execute when this action is performed). My class structure:

```
   < Order >

       < Product >

          <Customer >
```

There is no inheritance, more Association < Order > has < Product >, < Customer > has < Order > .

Does this structure look ok? I've noticed that I don't handle the "Quantity" separately, I was just going to add this into the "Product" class, but, do you think it should be a class of it's own?

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Usually Customers `have` Orders `of` your products.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Just seen the mistake, it was a typo :)

Comment: There's no hierarchy here.  Your company has products it sells to customers.  It does this through line-item records on invoices which associate a product and a quantity to the invoice.  Hold on while I find a sample schema...

Comment: Something like this: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC210940.gif

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hey that's great :)! Makes more sense, but I only dealing with Ordering a product, therefore I shouldn't really need to consider Customers, correct?

Comment: If it's not a customer, it's a vendor. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I get it :) I like this answer, so if you can (when you get time) to put it as an answer, I'll mark this as solved :). Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your company has products it sells to customers. It does this through line-item records on invoices which associate a product and a quantity to the invoice. A typical schema might look something like this:

[image]